# Cutting background color diagonally with CSS

Tags: css

How to cut away part of a background color diagonally using CSS?

Here is an example

[image]

```css
.item {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 30px;
  background-color: #565453;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  width: 52%;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">New Music</div>
```

Comment: don't repeat the same question. The duplicate is giving you all the possible solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `linear-gradient` starting with `transparent` as the first *color-stop*

```css
.item {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 30px;
  background: linear-gradient(225deg, transparent 0, transparent 50px, #565453 0, #565453 100%);
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  width: 52%;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">New Music</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively to Fabrizios excellent solution you could also use `clip-path` to solve your problem

```css
.item {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 30px;
  background-color: #565453;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  width: 52%;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, calc(100% - 50px) 0, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="item">New Music</div>
```

Also check out this handy generator for all sorts of paths: https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this with the background color you asked for:

```css
#AboutUs {
  height: 30px;
  width: 400px;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #4C4C4C 90%, #E3E3E3 10%);
  padding: 5px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
}

#text {
  margin-left: 150px;
  height: 30px;
  width: 190px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="AboutUs">New Music

</div>
```